# How to mock @Input variables in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

A function called in onInit requires a variable brought in from input.

How can I mock a dummy input so that i can pass

`expect(component).toBeTruthy();`

Something along the lines of:

```
{something: [{key:'value'}]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just set it directly on your component when you create it in your test, for example in your `beforeEach`:

```
let component: MyComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.myInput = { something: [{ key:'value' }] };
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```